# Override bulk.js and bulk.phtml vendor files on my app/code

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento2.4.5, template-override, bulk

Do you see anything obviously wrong here?

I am trying to override

1. vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/bulk.phtml
2. vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js

I tried adding there files to my local

1. app/design/adminhtml/TTT/FFF/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js
2. app/design/adminhtml/TTT/FFF/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/bulk.phtml

Then this

1. app/design/adminhtml/TTT/FFF/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/bulk.phtml
2. app/design/adminhtml/TTT/FFF/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js

None of these changes worked.

Can anyone told me the exact path I should be using or point me at what's wrong on those I tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've created a custom admin theme called TTT_FFF with theme.xml and registration.php files? See: https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-admin-theme-in-magento-2/

HTH, Tom